# Tap quickly giving corrupted navigation bar and crash

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nested

I have a UIViewController with UIBarButtonItem on in the top left position. Tapping this button pushes a another UIViewController which has the usual back button also top left.

The problem is if you click repeatedly in the top left quickly (easier in the Simulator, but also happens on real devices), you get:

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar

Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

and the app crashes shortly after with

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Can't add self as subview
```

It’s because the push animation is starting before the pop animation has completed I guess.

I think this only has only started happening in iOS 8 (still happens in 8.1.1).

How can it be fixed or worked around?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button until the view has finished presenting

Comment: Well, yea, but this is just an example, I have many push and pops throughout the app. Can someone confirm it is an introduced bug in iOS 8 and how does everyone deal with this?